# Value of type 'Binder<UIImage?>' has no member 'bind'

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, data-binding, rx-swift

I want to bind my ImageView to viewModel for save my selected image to Core Data.

**My code look like this:**

```
class FoodViewModel: FoodViewModelType {
    var foodImage: BehaviorRelay<UIImage?>
    //... another code
}
```

**My controller:**

```
class NewFoodViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var foodImageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       //... another code
       self.foodImageView.rx.image.bind(to: foodViewModel.foodImage).disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
    }
}
```

**And i get error:**

> Value of type Binder < UIImage? > has no member 'bind'

How to save my image to Core Data with good MVVM practice?

**Update**

I am choose photo in view controller:

```
func chooseImagePickerAction(source: UIImagePickerController.SourceType) {
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(source) {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.sourceType = source
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

@objc func foodImageViewTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Photo path", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    let cameraAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default) { (action) in
        self.chooseImagePickerAction(source: .camera)
    }

    let photoLibAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Photo", style: .default) { (action) in
        self.chooseImagePickerAction(source: .photoLibrary)
    }

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default)

    alertController.addAction(cameraAction)
    alertController.addAction(photoLibAction)
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

extension NewFoodViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

        let info = convertFromUIImagePickerControllerInfoKeyDictionary(info)

        foodImageView.image = info[convertFromUIImagePickerControllerInfoKey(UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage)] as? UIImage
        foodImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    private func convertFromUIImagePickerControllerInfoKeyDictionary(_ input: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any]) -> [String: Any] {
        return Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: input.map {key, value in (key.rawValue, value)})
    }

    private func convertFromUIImagePickerControllerInfoKey(_ input: UIImagePickerController.InfoKey) -> String {
        return input.rawValue
    }
}
```

And in viewDidLoad (without image):

```
saveNewFoodBarButtonItem.rx.tap.subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] _ in
    guard let self = self else { return }

    let foodViewModel = FoodViewModel()

    self.foodQuantityTypeTextField.rx.text.bind(to: foodViewModel.foodQuantityType).disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
    self.foodShelfLifeTextField.rx.text.bind(to: foodViewModel.foodShelfLife).disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
    self.foodCategoryTextField.rx.text.bind(to: foodViewModel.foodCategoryId).disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
    self.foodQuantityTextField.rx.text.bind(to: foodViewModel.foodQuantity).disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
    self.foodNameTextField.rx.text.bind(to: foodViewModel.foodName).disposed(by: self.disposeBag)

    foodViewModel.saveNewFood(fridgeViewModel: self.fridgeViewModel!)

    self.dismiss(animated: true)
}).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be downloading the image in viewModel and bind it to imageView in view controller using `foodImage.bind(to: foodImageView.rx.image).disposed(by: self.disposeBag)`

Comment: I want to create new food from selected user image (from iPhone photo library).

Comment: Show us the code where you insert the image into the UIImageView if that's what you want to do.

Comment: I am update my question. Added code

Answer (score 4):

UIImageView is not bindable because it is an output view, not an input view, i.e., you push things into it, it doesn't push things out.

In order to emit an image to your view model, you need to do it the at the point where you push the image into the UIImageView.